# Windows Key + Shift + Arrows not working with Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

`WinKey + Shift + [Arrow]` is the Windows keyboard shortcut (hotkey) for moving windows between monitors. I have 2 monitors set up side-by-side and since yesterday noticed that I could not use this hotkey to move a maximized Chrome between them.

What I have tried:

- Using a non-maximized Chrome window. **The hotkey works when Chrome is not maximized.**
- Restarting Windows. No change.
- Using other `WinKey + [Arrow]` hotkeys with Chrome. All other combinations have worked when Chrome is maximized and not.
- Using `WinKey + Shift + [Arrow]` with other applications. It works with all other applications I've tried (Evernote, OneNote, Firefox, VSCode) both maximized and not.
- Using an incognito window with no extensions allowed. No change.
- Using Chrome Canary. It also does not work with that application.
- Checking my keyboard using KeyboardTest. The relevant keys don't seem to have problems.
- Trying with a different monitor. No change.

Notes:

- When I use the hotkey on a maximized Chrome window and then restore (un-maximize) the window, it moves to the other monitor.
- When I use the hotkey multiple times on a maximized Chrome window and then restore the window, it moves off-screen somewhere. I can use the hotkey to move it back to one of my monitors.

I have searched online for solutions but they fall into the categories of

1. All WinKey movement shortcuts do not work
2. Chrome does not accept any keyboard input
3. [Semi-relevant and Unanswered](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/L2p2sCVEE8M)

Versions:

- Windows 10 v1607 build 14931.1000
- Chrome 56.0.2896.3 dev

I would appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: Just FYI, I'm using Chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit) and Windows 10 Pro v1607 build 14393.222 and it's working for my 2 monitors. I was having some very weird issues with Chrome and they resolved when Chrome updated a few days ago. Have you tried resetting Chrome (the last item under Chrome's advanced settings)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried resetting but saw no improvement. I uninstalled Chrome and installed from the Beta channel (Version 55.0.2883.21 beta-m (64-bit)) and the hotkey seemed to work. When I uninstalled that and installed dev it no longer worked. It looks like a bug was filed [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=656001) already, I'll just leave a comment there.

Comment: now it works but it causes the window to go black and dead :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a regression in Chrome and fixed in [656001](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=656001).